# Existance of a simple function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function. Suppose that $\varepsilon, M > 0$ are given. Show that there is some simple function $\varphi : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x) - \varphi(x)| < \varepsilon$ for all $x$ except where $|f(x)| > M$.

I was wondering if I could get a hint.

Comment: Partition $[-M,M]$ into subintervals of equal length $L<\epsilon$. Note there are finitely many of these, call them $I_1$, $I_2$, $\ldots\,$, $I_k$. Form your simple function using the intervals $f^{-1}(I_1)$, $\ldots\,$, $f^{-1}(I_k)$, and  $f^{-1}([-M,M]^c)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** a bounded measurable function is an uniform limit of a sequence of simple functions. Use this with $f\chi_{\{|f|\leqslant M\}}$.